# Does limewater cure cancer?

Tags: cancer

In Macedonia, [limewater](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limewater) (calcium hydroxide) is used as a folk remedy for cancer. The case was presented on television in Macedonia that patients with metastases were cured by drinking lime water and yoghurt each morning.

Does limewater cure cancer?

Comment: I just want to make sure I have edited it correctly. You are talking about mineralized water, not dilute fruit juice, right?

Comment: It is about calcium oxide (called lime or quicklime) mixed, or "slaked" with water.I guess that in English is called slaked lime. It is not dilute fruit juice.

Comment: Thanks. It is called limewater in English too, but when I searched for some examples of other people making the claim for notability, I found lots of claims that lemon & lime juice would cure cancer, which made me wonder if I had misunderstood.

Comment: Thank you, I know that lime water is very alkaline but I also know that undiluted lime water is use as a cure for cancer in Makedonia. One woman claimed on TV that she so cured metastasized (4 metastases) breast cancer. She was, two months earlier, discharged from the hospital as a non treatable

Comment: very related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13604/does-sodium-bicarbonate-reduce-the-risk-of-cancer

Comment: Should we even allow questions regarding "cures" for diseases or conditions that have no known cure? Especially "home remedies". The very idea that some tea or vitamins could cure lymphoma or even syphilis is a dangerous one. I see a lot of "Does X cure cancer?" questions in the related frame.

Comment: Also, there's at least a hundred different types of cancer, and research has shown that the cure for one (testicular cancer for example, is usually curable now) isn't going to work for every other type. So this question is too broad.